# How to omit built-in functions from call graph

Tags: c++, c, gcc, call-graph

I generated my C/C++ program's call graph using gcc, however the graph contains a lot of built-in functions such as strcmp, fprintf etc. which I am not interested in. Is there any gcc options that can help to omit those kinds of functions? I know that egypt has an option --omit, but this requires users to specify a list of functions which they know in advance. This means that if i want to remove all of the built-in functions above, I need to have a complete list of the functions which I am not sure where to get.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The complete list of the standard library's functions can be found in the language standard. That list, however, does not include helper, compiler-specific functions.

See, for example, `Annex B/Library summary` of the C standard from 1999.

If you don't have the standard, get its drafts online.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the instrumentation function yourself. See [this link](http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2010/09/gcc-function-instrumentation.html) for more info on how.
Implementing the intrumentation function, lets you specify a function that will be called before every function call, and it will be passed the addresses of the called function and the address it was called from.

After that you can use the `addr2line` tool to convert the addresses from the instrumented run. That lets you extract the functions and lets you filter them. You'd need to parse the text files and build a call graph yourself, but the `dot` language is laughably easy to get going with.

Comment: Thanks @Morten Jensen. I was thinking of that solution, but just wonder if there is a lightweight ready-to-use solution from gcc. for example, a gcc option like -fno-standard-funtions

Comment: @user2197352 yeah it really is a far way to go just to get what you want :S .. what kind of output is GCC giving you ? a .dot file or?

Comment: yes, it is a .dot file. I know that I can "grep" and "remove" the records relating to those functions from the .dot file. However, this also requires a predefined black list of the functions as I mentioned in the original post. I just thought that gcc may have that kind of option. It seems like the black-list solution is the only option now.

Comment: @user2197352 I don't know of any other solution :( tried googling and skimming the gcc manual, but I can't find a flag that seems to do that..